# nest.js UseGuards, Object is possibly 'undefined' when using inheritance and @UseGuards

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm do extend one of my controller so it will takes some of his parent useful method & instantiation.

But doing so, I cannot reach on of the variable I declare within the @UseGuards

```js
@Controller()
export class BaseController {
  constructor(protected _target: string) {}
}
```

```js
@Controller('ChildController')
export class ChildController extends BaseController {
  constructor() {
   super('child')
  }

  
  @Post()
  @UseGuards(new AuthGuard('checkAccess'), new RolesGuard(this._target)) // <-- error over the this.
  async create(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response, @Body() newItem: any) {
    const item = await this._controllerService.create(newItem)

    return new ApiResponseHandler(res).withObject(item).withStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK).build()
  }
}
```

[image]

```
@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  target: string

  constructor(target?: string) {
    this.target = target
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    return this.myControlMethod(context) // use this.target within it
  }
}
```

I have the feeling I do not understand fully the the way `@UseGuards` works

#### Objectif

I have multiple endpoint that have similar logics. For example here, the `target` will be use to find the first item, in this `target` table that match the id.

Comment: Please share the implementation of `RolesGuard` as well

Comment: @JesseCarter I did the update

Comment: What are you wanting to do with passing `this._target`? Could you use the `ExecutionContext`'s `getClass` and `getHandler` instead?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I did update my question, is it clearer  ? `getClass` seems to be interesting, but I'll then have to kind of `.split('Controller')[0].toLowerCase()`. Which seems to be a bit dirty. Did I understand it correctly ?